# Find the nearest/closest lower value of an element in a sorted 1D array

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if it is possible to find the closest lower element in a non-empty sorted array for an element that may be there or may not be there. Elements can be repeated also any number of times. All elements of the array +ve.

For example, if we had the values [2,5,6,7,7,8,9] and we are looking for the element closest lower to 6, it should return 5, because 5 is the biggest number in the array, that is smaller than 6. 
Similarly, if we're looking for the element closest lower to 9, it should return 8, because 8 is the biggest number in the array, that is smaller than 9. 
And if the closest lower element is not found, return -1 like if we're looking for the element closest lower to 1, it should return -1, because there is no such element which can be lower than 1. Here -1 represents that there's no such value is present in the array which is closest lower to the element

I have tried this below code. Is it all right? If I'm missing something, please help me. Java code will be more helpful.

```
static int find(int[] a, int target)
{
    int n = a.length;

    if(target <= a[0])
        return -1;

    if(target > a[n-1])
        return a[n-1];

    int i=0,j=n,mid=0;

    while(i<j)
    {
        mid = (i+j)/2;
        if(target <= a[mid])
        {
            if( mid >0 & target> a[mid-1] )
            {   
                 return a[mid-1]; 
            }

            j= mid;
        }
        else
        {
            if( mid<(n-1) & target > a[mid+1] )
            {   
                 return a[mid+1]; 
            }

            i= mid+1;
        }
    }
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: What should happen for empty arrays? What about negative numbers in the array - what is -1 supposed to mean then? Your code is hard to read, which is why I refrain from digging deeper. I suggest to invest into, at least, clean syntax.

Comment: No sir. All +ve no and there should be at least one element. Here -1 means that there're no such value is present in the array which is closest lower to the element

Comment: @C-Otto sir, I have updated the required information you needed. And I've also tried to give a clean syntax. Can you please help me now?

Answer (score 2):

There exists a standard binarySearch function.

```
static int find(int[] a, int target) {
    int position = Arrays.binarySearch(a, target);
    if (position >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Found at index " + position);
    } else {
        int insertIndex = ~position;
        System.out.println("Insert position at index " + insertIndex);
        position = insertIndex;
    }
    return position;
}
```

When not found it delives the ones-complement of the insert position, as shown above. This means when the result is negative, the item is not found.

It does more or less what you did, but on not finding, it cleverly return a negative: ~ insert position (or -insert position - 1).

```
/**
 * Search the next smaller array element.
 * @param a the array sorted in ascending order.
 * @param target the value to keep below.
 * @return the greatest smaller element, or -1.
 */
static int findNextSmaller(int[] a, int target) {
    int i= Arrays.binarySearch(a, target);
    if (i >= 0) {
        --i;
        while (i>= 0 && a[i] == target) {
            --i;
        }
    } else {
        i = ~i;
        --i;
    }
    return i == -1 ? -1 : a[i];
}
```

Or, as `int` is discrete:

```
static int findNextSmaller(int[] a, int target) {
    int i= Arrays.binarySearch(a, target - 1);
    if (i >= 0) {
        return target - 1;
    }
    i = ~i;
    --i;
    return i == -1 ? -1 : a[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort sir. But sir, I don't need to find the element in the array. Given an element and a non-empty +ve integer array (in which the given element may present or may not be and elements can be repeated at any number of times), I need to find the closest smaller element of the given element in the array.

Comment: @Sushovan I suggest you read the Javadoc of the suggested method, because it describes how it handles missing values.

Comment: This method gives the index of the element >= the search value. I'll add code.

Comment: Problem with using `binarySearch` like this is the assumption that array is sorted, yet OP doesn't mention that, except for giving an example array that is sorted (but I will attribute that to a natural human bias for sorted data examples rather than actual requirement).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov see my comment I added to my answer. According to the title the array indeed has to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Using streams:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class FindNearestLowestValue {

    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {2,5,6,7,7,8,9};
        int searchVal = 6;
        // reverse the order so the first element of the filtered stream is the result
        System.out.println(
            IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                .map(i -> array[array.length - 1 - i])
                .filter(n -> n < searchVal)
                .findFirst().orElse(-1)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't "closest", this is first that is lesser.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov And Sushovan's description of the needed functionality is different from that in what way? Especially the examples are exactly what I implemented.

Comment: he says that from array of `[2, 5, 6, 8]`, when looking for `6`, the algorithm should return `5`. Yours does it, but only for example input. If I change the array, your algorithm breaks. For instance, given `[2, 6, 5, 3, 8]`, it'll return `3`. And this is a valid example, since nowhere did OP say that array is ordered.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov According to the title the array has to be sorted. Yours isn't. An unsorted array would break the other answer as well, since binarySearch requires a sorted array, too

Comment: Oh, the title. Haven't looked at the title. Ok, then your solution is fine, if a little on the heavy side performance-wise.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov While "sorted" is mentioned in the title, "performant" isn't ;-)

Comment: True. Which is why the solution is fine. It only needs a tiny mod anyway, if OP is concerned with performance, he can add it himself.